# android studio casting warning

Tags: android, android-studio

I mistakenly disable this feature but I don't know how to enable again. The feature is that warns me when I cast an object to another class. For example:

```
ImageView scanner;
TextView errorMessage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    errorMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorMessage);
    scanner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanner); // studio warns me when I do this cast, but I mistakenly close this feature
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

this is the exact solution:

[image: this is the exact solution]

Answer (score 0):

You decalred scanner as imageview on top

```
ImageView scanner;
```

and you are tying to cast it to textview in oncreate, that is not possible.

Change

```
scanner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanner);
```

to

```
scanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scanner);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following trick:

**Step 1:**
Find the inspector icon (a human with a cap) at the bottom right corner of your Android Studio.

**Step 2:**
Click on that and you can find a seek bar. It will help you to enable/disable or even you can configure it according to your need.

[image]